# Liferay 7.1 - Restricted access for porlets/modules to a virtual instances (company)

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I created a new virtual instances.

I want to know if I can restrict my custom portlets to be available and to be added in only one virtual instances ?

And, I want to know if Hooks and Fragments can be restricted the same way ?
(For exemples, I have a fragment for the user personal bar, and hook for login hook. I want to activate those for only one VI and not for the other).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By deploying your plugins to the server, they're available for everything running on the server, e.g. all virtual instances.

I believe themes had a declarative way to enumerate the companyId (or companyIds) for which they apply, but other plugins don't have this.

That being said, with a little bit of more effort, you can still achieve what you'll need: Your plugins most likely have access to the companyId and can do their own checks. You can also customize permissions per virtual instance to remove the "ADD_TO_PAGE" permission for certain portlets for everybody on a virtual instance.

For Fragments you're probably asking about JSP fragments, as CMS fragments are specific to a site, not even an instance. There you'd have to go with the conditional: If you're on the companyId that you want to change: Render. Otherwise: Skip the modification. However, you should minimize Fragment usage as much as you can: They're quickly developed, but then quickly turn into maintenance monsters: You're dealing with the implementation level of the underlying release and nothing shields you from a change in a later version of the same JSP that you then must 3-way-merge.

Comment: Ok so first I want to use permission per virtual instances on modules.
So I have done that in resources/META-INF/resources/resource-actions/default.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE resource-action-mapping PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Resource Action Mapping 7.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-resource-action-mapping_7_0_0.dtd">
<resource-action-mapping>
    <portlet-resource>
        <portlet-name>MyPortlet</portlet-name>
        <permissions>
            <supports>
                <action-key>ACCESS_IN_CONTROL_PANEL</action-key>
                <action-key>VIEW</action-key>
            </supports>
        </permissions>
    </portlet-resource>
</resource-action-mapping>

Comment: How can I restrict this ACCESS_IN_CONTROL_PANEL per virtual instance ? (I want the first one to have this permission and the second one to remove this permission)

Comment: `default.xml` provides the defaults. To override the defaults, you'll need the API - most likely on [ResourcePermission](https://docs.liferay.com/dxp/portal/7.3-latest/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/ResourcePermissionLocalService.html). Your decision what the defaults are, what you change it to through the API (e.g. default to no permissions, grant them through API, or vice versa). Key is the `companyId` parameter in the API. Also, note [this ancient but still relevant](https://liferay.dev/en/b/the-right-tool-for-the-job-chapter-1-instances) information.

Comment: Ok  I understand the behaviour. Do you have an example of a ResourcePermission for a portlet ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that available. My recommendation: Check reading permissions through that API, configure a portlet manually to do as you expect, then read values again and compare. Notice that an admin with permissions to edit permissions on a virtual instance will be able to revert this - depending on the level of mischief you're expecting, you might want to limit those permissions on the VI as well. And while I don't advocate looking at the database ever: Sometimes directly reading those values is easier than programmatically fetching them over and over. Just don't write through SQL!